# Eleminate 'new' form by adding empty key to database and using edit form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I hope the title isn't too unclear..

Lets say we are writing the back-end of a (web) application with a user database. There are users, and those users have other stuff that admins can connect to them like admin notes, etc.

For instance the admin notes you'd have to write:

1. A form for creating and filling in the note;
2. A form for editing the note if necessary;
3. A view page for viewing the note (with delete and edit buttons)

Now I'm feeling lazy (And I'm sure I'm not alone ;] ) and I don't want to write extra code. So I'm thinking of 'eliminating' the Create form.

Instead now, my plan is to:

Create a button 'New'. When clicked on that button it will create a key with an empty row in the MySQL table. Once created it will redirect to the edit page of that row. Of course everything will be empty and Information can be added right away.

Problem 1: If somebody navigates away from this edit page I understand an empty key will remain in the MySQL table. 
Solution for problem: Simple check and delete for empty rows.

What other problems (other than unrealistic high id(primary key)'s could occur?

Looking forward for everyone's thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution to this would be to write your form in such a way that it expects to be bound with the data you're working on - when you're working on a new instance of something, the form gets bound with empty/default data - when you're working on an existing instance, it gets bound with that instance (or, when you're working on a 'new' one - construct the instance to bind it to the form, but don't actually save it).

By doing it this way you still have the traditional create/edit pages, but you only need to implement your form logic once (and you don't have to worry about keeping your database in sync with what's actually been saved).

Comment: You're the only one who replied, but nonetheless a great solution. Cheers :)